# I don't understand this Python TypeError

Tags: python, linode

I am trying to use the [Linode API](https://www.linode.com/api) along with this [linode-python](https://github.com/tjfontaine/linode-python/blob/master/linode/api.py) SDK to manage my Linode servers.  However, I'm getting a TypeError I don't understand when I run the [linode-disk-list()](https://www.linode.com/api/linode/linode.disk.list) command.

This is how the linode-python API defines the method I'm calling.  As you can see, a LinodeID is required.

```
@__api_request(required=['LinodeID'],
                 returns=[{u'CREATE_DT': u'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0',
                           u'DISKID': 'Disk ID',
                           u'ISREADONLY': '0 or 1',
                           u'LABEL': 'Disk label',
                           u'LINODEID': 'Linode ID',
                           u'SIZE': 'Size of disk (MB)',
                           u'STATUS': 'Status flag',
                           u'TYPE': "in ['ext3', 'swap', 'raw']",
                           u'UPDATE_DT': u'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0'}])
  def linode_disk_list(self, request):
    """Lists all disk images associated with a Linode."""
    pass
```

My code creates an instance of the Linode Python API per the SDK's instructions and then calls the linode_disk_list method:

```
from linode import api as linode_api

api = linode_api.Api(<my_api_key>)
linode_id = 1800300
disks = api.linode_disk_list(linode_id)
```

My code generates this error:

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I know I'm creating the api instance correctly as I'm using it to successfully call the linode_ip_list method prior to calling the disk list method.

Just to see what happens, if I don't provide the linode_id argument, I get this error:

```
linode.api.MissingRequiredArgument: 'LinodeID'
```

If I call the method with a linode ID, the error says I'm giving it two arguments.  But if I don't give it any arguments, it says I'm missing an argument.  At this point, I'm not sure if the LinodeID should be an integer or a string but I get the same error in either case.  How do I call this method so that I don't get the TypeError argument?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace? `wrapper()` is most likely [some internal method](https://github.com/tjfontaine/linode-python/blob/master/linode/api.py#L318) of the api you are using

Comment: Yes. Need to check __api_request decorator.

Comment: I tried importing traceback and then surrounding the api call with a try/except block and then doing "tb = traceback.format_exc()" but it's only pointing the line in my Python program where I'm making the api call.  Is there another way to do what you're asking?  BTW, I believe the wrapper starts at line 318 at the linode-python SDK line shown in the opening paragraph above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@__api_request` decorator takes a list for each of its arguments:

```
def __api_request(required=[], optional=[], returns=[]):
    """Decorator to define required and optional parameters"""
    for k in required:
      [...]
```

But, you are passing in an integer

```
linode_id = 1800300
disks = api.linode_disk_list(linode_id)
```

And you are getting conflicting error message about the amount of parameters because the `wrapper()` method takes an arbitrary amount of keyword arguments

```
 def wrapper(self, **kw):
```

Comment: Thanks (although your answer didn't directly answer my question).  After thinking about what you said and doing some more experimentation, I learned that the way to call the method is this: "disks = api.linode_disk_list(LinodeID=<lid>)".